# using vs2015+opencv 2.4.11, I want to write a plug-in for the small game called "jump in jump" in wechat. but the adb can not work

Tags: android, c++, opencv

using vs2015+opencv 2.4.11,
I want to write a plug-in for the small game called "jump in jump" in wechat, and I want to use the "adp" to get the image from my Android phone. but when I operate it,it says "'adb'is not an internal or external command, nor is it a running program Or batch file. "
what's more, when I cin "adb" in "cmd", it can operate successfully.

code as follow:

```
#include<opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include<iostream>
#include<math.h>
#include<stdlib.h>//rand()随机数头文件
#include <windows.h>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;



//全局变量定义区
Mat srcImage;
Mat dstImage;
Mat Character;

static int i = 0;
//get_screenshot();获取手机上的图像
void get_screenshot();
//Canny_Dec();边缘检测
void Canny_Dec(Mat& srcImage);
//获取Character坐标
Point get_Character_Loc(Mat& srcImage, Mat& Tem_img);
//获取下一个要跳的点
Point get_next_img_Loc(Mat& srcImage, Point& Character_Loc);
//计算距离
int get_distance(Point& first_point, Point& next_point);
//跳跃
void jump(int&g_distance);
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    system("color 3F");
    while (true)
    {
        get_screenshot();
        srcImage = imread("autojump.png");
        dstImage = srcImage.clone();
        Character = imread("./Template/character.png");
        //imshow("Character",Character);
        //cvtColor(srcImage,srcImage,CV_BGR2GRAY);
        Point next_p = get_Character_Loc(srcImage, Character);
        //cout<<"next_p:"<<1111<<endl;

        Point get_next = get_next_img_Loc(srcImage, next_p);

        int g_distance = get_distance(next_p, get_next);

        jump(g_distance);
        //cout<<"get_next_img_Loc:"<<get_next<<endl;
        circle(dstImage, get_next, 8, Scalar(0, 221, 2));
        //imshow("test",dstImage);
        imwrite("Canny.png", dstImage);
        Sleep(1000);
    }
    return 0;
}

void get_screenshot()
{
    system("adb shell screencap -p /sdcard/autojump.png");
    system("adb pull /sdcard/autojump.png");
}

Point get_Character_Loc(Mat& srcImage, Mat& Tem_img)
{
    matchTemplate(srcImage, Tem_img, dstImage, CV_TM_SQDIFF);
    double minVal, maxVal;
    Point minLoc, maxLoc, matchLoc;
    minMaxLoc(dstImage, &minVal, &maxVal, &minLoc, &maxLoc, Mat());
    matchLoc = minLoc; //matchLoc是最佳匹配的区域左上角点
    cout << "maxVal:" << maxVal << endl;
    rectangle(srcImage, Rect(matchLoc, Size(Character.cols, Character.rows)), Scalar(255, 255, 0), 1, 8, 0);
    //Canny(srcImage,srcImage,1,10);
    putText(srcImage, "Wang", Point(matchLoc.x + Character.cols*0.5, matchLoc.y + Character.rows), 1, 2, Scalar(0, 0, 255));//画出Character小人的坐标
    return Point(matchLoc.x + Character.cols*0.5, matchLoc.y + Character.rows);
}

Point get_next_img_Loc(Mat& srcImage, Point& Character_Loc)
{
    cout << "get_next_img_Loc" << endl;
    cvtColor(srcImage, srcImage, CV_BGR2GRAY);
    GaussianBlur(srcImage, srcImage, Size(3, 3), 0);
    Canny(srcImage, srcImage, 3, 8);
    char AA[30];
    sprintf(AA, "get_next_img_Loc_%d.png", i);
    cout << AA << endl;
    imwrite(AA, srcImage);
    i++;
    //imshow("get",srcImage);
    cout << "Character_Loc.x:" << Character_Loc.x << endl;
    if (Character_Loc.x < 540)
    {
        for (int j = int(srcImage.rows*0.2);j<int(srcImage.rows*0.8);j++)
        {
            uchar* data = srcImage.ptr<uchar>(j);
            for (int i = 1079;i > 540;i--)
            {
                if (data[i] == 255)
                {
                    return Point(i, j);
                    //cout<<"Point:"<<Point(i,j)<<endl;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for (int j = int(srcImage.rows*0.2);j<int(srcImage.rows*0.8);j++)
        {
            uchar* data = srcImage.ptr<uchar>(j);
            for (int i = 0;i<540;i++)
            {
                if (data[i] == 255)
                    return Point(i, j);
            }
        }
    }
    return Character_Loc;
}

int get_distance(Point& first_point, Point& next_point)
{
    int A = first_point.x - next_point.x;
    int B = first_point.y - (next_point.y + 50);
    return int(pow(pow(A, 2) + pow(B, 2), 0.5));
}

void jump(int&g_distance)
{
    char AA[50];
    int distance_ = g_distance * 1.35;
    int rand_x = int(320 + rand() % 50); //加上随机数使得每次按压都是在点（320,410）-（370,460）之间
    int rand_y = int(410 + rand() % 50);
    sprintf(AA, "adb shell input swipe %d %d %d %d %d", rand_x, rand_y, rand_x, rand_y, distance_);
    cout << AA << endl;
    system(AA);
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you want to inspect your code with a debugger and check where its behavior doesn't meet your expectations.

Comment: ok , i  will have a try.